# Python web crawler (NameError: name 'spider' is not defined)

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm trying to run an example I found online at http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-in-under-50-lines-of-python-code/

However, I'm running into issues when running it via the Python 3.5.2 Shell.

`spider("http://www.dreamhost.com", "secure", 200)` 
gives me the message:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in  
    spider("http://www.dreamhost.com", "secure", 200) 
    NameError: name 'spider' is not defined

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser  
from urllib.request import urlopen  
from urllib import parse

class LinkParser(HTMLParser):

def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'a':
        for (key, value) in attrs:
            if key == 'href':
                newUrl = parse.urljoin(self.baseUrl, value)
                self.links = self.links + [newUrl]

def getLinks(self, url):
    self.links = []
    self.baseUrl = url
    response = urlopen(url)
    if response.getheader('Content-Type')=='text/html':
        htmlBytes = response.read()
        htmlString = htmlBytes.decode("utf-8")
        self.feed(htmlString)
        return htmlString, self.links
    else:
        return "",[]

def spider(url, word, maxPages):  
    pagesToVisit = [url]
    numberVisited = 0
    foundWord = False
    while numberVisited < maxPages and pagesToVisit != [] and not     foundWord:
    numberVisited = numberVisited +1
    url = pagesToVisit[0]
    pagesToVisit = pagesToVisit[1:]
    try:
        print(numberVisited, "Visiting:", url)
        parser = LinkParser()
        data, links = parser.getLinks(url)
        if data.find(word)>-1:
            foundWord = True
        pagesToVisit = pagesToVisit + links
        print(" **Success!**")
    except:
        print(" **Failed!**")
if foundWord:
    print("The word", word, "was found at", url)
else:
    print("Word never found")
```

Comment: How do you run it? What are all the instructions that you type in the REPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yourno,

You have indentation problem in your code buddy. After defining class, there are no indentation before method `handle_starttag` and `getLinks`. Also in function `spider`, there are indetation missing in `if-else` section. Kindly check your code against the code posted on link that you have provided. Kindly find the below updated working code:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser  
from urllib.request import urlopen  
from urllib import parse

# We are going to create a class called LinkParser that inherits some
# methods from HTMLParser which is why it is passed into the definition
class LinkParser(HTMLParser):

    # This is a function that HTMLParser normally has
    # but we are adding some functionality to it
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # We are looking for the begining of a link. Links normally look
        # like <a href="www.someurl.com"></a>
        if tag == 'a':
            for (key, value) in attrs:
                if key == 'href':
                    # We are grabbing the new URL. We are also adding the
                    # base URL to it. For example:
                    # www.netinstructions.com is the base and
                    # somepage.html is the new URL (a relative URL)
                    #
                    # We combine a relative URL with the base URL to create
                    # an absolute URL like:
                    # www.netinstructions.com/somepage.html
                    newUrl = parse.urljoin(self.baseUrl, value)
                    # And add it to our colection of links:
                    self.links = self.links + [newUrl]

    # This is a new function that we are creating to get links
    # that our spider() function will call
    def getLinks(self, url):
        self.links = []
        # Remember the base URL which will be important when creating
        # absolute URLs
        self.baseUrl = url
        # Use the urlopen function from the standard Python 3 library
        response = urlopen(url)
        # Make sure that we are looking at HTML and not other things that
        # are floating around on the internet (such as
        # JavaScript files, CSS, or .PDFs for example)
        if response.getheader('Content-Type')=='text/html':
            htmlBytes = response.read()
            # Note that feed() handles Strings well, but not bytes
            # (A change from Python 2.x to Python 3.x)
            htmlString = htmlBytes.decode("utf-8")
            self.feed(htmlString)
            return htmlString, self.links
        else:
            return "",[]

# And finally here is our spider. It takes in an URL, a word to find,
# and the number of pages to search through before giving up
def spider(url, word, maxPages):  
    pagesToVisit = [url]
    numberVisited = 0
    foundWord = False
    # The main loop. Create a LinkParser and get all the links on the page.
    # Also search the page for the word or string
    # In our getLinks function we return the web page
    # (this is useful for searching for the word)
    # and we return a set of links from that web page
    # (this is useful for where to go next)
    while numberVisited < maxPages and pagesToVisit != [] or not foundWord:
        numberVisited = numberVisited +1
        # Start from the beginning of our collection of pages to visit:
        url = pagesToVisit[0]
        pagesToVisit = pagesToVisit[1:]
        try:
            print(numberVisited, "Visiting:", url)
            parser = LinkParser()
            data, links = parser.getLinks(url)
            if data.find(word)>-1:
                foundWord = True
                foundAtUrl = url
                # Add the pages that we visited to the end of our collection
                # of pages to visit:
                pagesToVisit = pagesToVisit + links
                print(" **Success!**")
            #Added else, so if desired word not found, then make foundWord = False
            else:
                foundWord = False
        except:
            print(" **Failed!**")
        #Moved this if-else condition block inside while loop, so for every url, it will give us message whether the desired word found or not
        if foundWord:
            print("The word", word, "was found at", url)
        else:
            print("Word never found")

spider("http://www.dreamhost.com", "secure", 200)
```

Kindly let me know, if you still have any issue/query.

Comment: Thank you for the response Khan.  Unfortunately still running into the original error even with the "working code" that you provided.

Comment: Hello @EmilioPagan-Yourno, yeah I got to know that you are using python shell to run the code. I have updated my above code. It will work definitely. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I figured it out!

Comment: Any idea why it stops after finding the first keyword? Instead of traversing the 200 pages and looking for each instance that the word "secure" is mentioned? http://imgur.com/a/EYUOr

Comment: Oh, let me check, I'll have to go through the link that you provided. Will let you know.

Comment: Well @EmilioPagan-Yourno, whoever posted that tutorial, really messed up whole. The code stops after finding the first keyword, because in `spider` method, in `while` loop condition, it has given `not foundWord` with `and` operator, and when it found word, it assigns `True` to `foundWord` and in while condition it becomes false and it breaks out of the loop. To achieve the same, first replace `and` with `or`. Second, add one line after `foundWord = True`, `foundAtUrl = url` and replace `url` with `foundAtUrl` in last `if-else` condition. And you are good to go. Let me know.

Comment: Hey @EmilioPagan-Yourno, I have updated code above, kindly find it and go through it, you'll find the required changes.

Comment: Hey @EmilioPagan-Yourno, one advise, not to use pages as much as 200, as it will take so much time to go though and find the desired word. For testing use 5 or 10. Thank you.

Comment: You're awesome!  How do we keep in contact?  Do you have any free time to work on paid projects?

Comment: Hey @Emilio Pagan-Yourno, thanks man. If your problem had solved, kindly accept the answer. Mostly I have free time on weekends only, so if you have any projects or something, let me know.